# Why checking for .is(':visible') never evaluated

Tags: jquery

I'm wondering why checking for visibility is never evaluated in this particular function.  It works fine in other functions. I understand that .is (':visible') is a Boolean(true/false) if I have the code the way below it works fine

```
if($("#complete").is(':hidden')) {  
   $("#complete").show();
   $("#img5").hide();

 }  


 else if($("#complete").is(':visible')) { 
    $("#complete").hide();
    $("#img5").show();



   }
```

if I add more functionality after checking for hidden and before checking for  visibility, visibility checking for this element never evaluated.

```
    if($("#complete").is(':hidden')) {  
       $("#complete").show();
       $("#img5").hide();
       $("#continue").hide();
       $("#addtocart").show(); 


     }  


    if($( ".g_card" ).on('click', function() {
         $('#addon_1').addClass('baddon_1add'); 
         $("#gift_occasion").toggle(); 

     })); 

       $("#g_minus").on('click', function(e){
         e.stopPropagation();        
         $('#addon_1').removeClass('baddon_1add').addClass('.baddon_1');
         }); 

else if($("#complete").is(':visible')) { 
        $("#complete").hide();
        $("#img5").show();
        $("#continue").show();
        $("#addtocart").hide(); 


   }  /*This if never evaluated after adding other conditions*/                                                                  Thanking You In Advance
```

Comment: Post a complete example please. Include your HTML.

Comment: There are numerous errors in your JS. If you tell us exactly what you're trying to achieve, then we can help you.

Comment: You have something other than a valid `if` block before the `else if`, so the `else if` isn't connected to any `if` block, which means it is both syntactically invalid and wouldn't logically work.  Use good indentation, and you will be able to spot these problems quickly. JSFiddle has a "Tidy Up" button that puts better indentation on your code and shows this issue here: http://jsfiddle.net/obs2Lw5t/.

Comment: Just a performance note: Are you aware that `$("#complete")` has to search the items in your DOM for a match. In your first block of code above, you have this expression 4 times. Better to do it once and save the result in a variable if you want your code to be efficient.

Comment: `if($("...").click(...))`???

Answer (score 0):

Easier to see if you fix your formatting you'll notice that the 2nd if is completed with a semicolon ; and the else has no if that it belongs to.

```
if($("#complete").is(':hidden')) {  
   $("#complete").show();
   $("#img5").hide();
   $("#continue").hide();
   $("#addtocart").show(); 
 }  


if($( ".g_card" ).on('click', function() {
     $('#addon_1').addClass('baddon_1add'); 
     $("#gift_occasion").toggle(); 
     })
 );  // End If

// Always runs
   $("#g_minus").on('click', function(e){
     e.stopPropagation();        
     $('#addon_1').removeClass('baddon_1add').addClass('.baddon_1');
     }); 

// else to what if?? no if's here
else if($("#complete").is(':visible')) { 
    $("#complete").hide();
    $("#img5").show();
    $("#continue").show();
    $("#addtocart").hide(); 


}
```

Edit: mattytommo's solution is better than mine

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to my questions that works for what I’m trying to accomplish. As I stated that I have an accordion type of application only one element should be allowed to open at a time. The application checks to see if element are visible before another element is allowed to open.  If element is visible code will hide it.
The issue I was having was that once the element was checked to see if hidden in a particular function and if it was it had to be made visible because that would be the only way you could see the siblings and be able to do clicks on them to add and remove classes which allowed adding a border and background color on plus and on minus button it removed the color border and background color setting it back to its original color.
You could not check for visibility and hide things if visible because to see siblings’ element had to be visible but I still had to check for visibility before I could open another element on the accordion.

```
    if($( ".g_card" ).on('click', function(e) { 
        e.stopPropagation();   
       $('#addon_1').addClass('baddon_1add'); 
       $("#gift_occasion").toggle();  
     })); 

    $("#g_minus").on('click', function(e){
         e.stopPropagation();        
   $('#addon_1').removeClass('baddon_1add').addClass('.baddon_1');
         }); 

 if($("#complete").is(':hidden')) {  
    $("#complete").show();
    $("#img5").hide();
    $("#continue").hide();
    $("#addtocart").show(); 
 }  

  else if($('#complete').is(':visible')) { 
          $("#complete").hide();
          $("#img5").show();
          $("#continue").show();
          $("#addtocart").hide(); 


  }
```